# A request for the USB device descriptor failed

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, bluetooth

My Bluetooth mouse has suddenly stopped working. In device manager it says:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed.
```

- The same mouse works perfectly on other laptops.
- It used to work in this particular laptop also but it suddenly stopped.
- Sometimes it works for 10-15 seconds before again failing to the mentioned error.

I have tried the almost all solution given [here](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-device-descriptor-request-failed-unknown-usb-device-in-windows-10):
Except # 7 since I cant find that option.

Anyone with any possible causes and solutions for this problem?

Comment: Does this happen with other mice?  Do other USB devices work fine?  "Other laptops".. also windows machines I assume.  I don't have an answer for you but these questions will help us help you. :)  I suggest trying a Linux Live disk and see if the problem happens there.  Not to convert you to Linux, rather to figure out the likelihood that this is a hardware or software (to include OS) problem.

Comment: Is it really Bluetooth? If so are you using a USB Bluetooth dongle? If so do other Bluetooth devices work with the same dongle? In any case the problem isn't the mouse, it's the dongle (or the USB port). But maybe it's a regular wireless mouse with its own receiver dongle in which case is the same dongle + mouse pair you've tested successfully in other computers? If actually Bluetooth are you also testing the pair or just the mouse paired with other BTs? You see, there's a lot of information missing an some parts really make me doubt about it being Bluetooth but you tell us...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an Intel 8265 wifi+bt card on a dell pc. All worked until recently and now windows doesn't recognize that bluetooth is installed. Same error in device manager.

Comment: For anyone who stumbled on this and is convinced its a hardware issue, I took the nuclear option and reinstalled windows and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my laptop (HP Elitebook) with Windows 10.
In my case, I wasn't using a dongle. Just a bluetooth mouse paired with my laptop bluetooth chip.
I tried uninstalling the device.
I tried restarting the laptop in safe mode.
I tried updating all drivers, firmware and BIOS.
All were temporary solutions and the mouse stopped working at next day or few days after.
I read there that other people fixed it letting the battery completely dried to discharge all laptop components.
I know that is not healthy for the battery so I just tried opening the laptop (not recommended if you are not sure what you are doing), disconnecting the battery and push the power button for some seconds to discharge all the laptop components that way.

I'll let you know in a couple of days if this fixed my issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140793)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).